# TapGestureRecognizer not responding in xamarin forms

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm facing a pretty weird problem trying to catch taps on certain images on my screen first here is my xaml code for a popup window implemented as a View :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="NumbersRaceXamarin.YesNoPopupMessages">
  <ContentView.Content>
    <RelativeLayout HeightRequest="190" WidthRequest="280">
      <Image x:Name="bg" Source="compbar_01.png" Aspect="Fill" HeightRequest="190" WidthRequest="330" Opacity="0.9" InputTransparent ="true"/>
      <StackLayout WidthRequest="280" Spacing="0" RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width , Factor=0.1,Constant=0}" RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height , Factor=0.02,Constant=0}">
        <Label x:Name="message" FontSize="15"></Label>
        <StackLayout WidthRequest="70" HeightRequest="30" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center"> 
          <RelativeLayout WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30" VerticalOptions="Center">
            <Image x:Name="minus" Source="startbottuns_01.png" Aspect="Fill" HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30"/>
            <Label  x:Name="minusTB" Text="-" FontSize="16" HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"></Label>
          </RelativeLayout>
          <Label  x:Name="qtyTB" Text="1" FontSize="8" HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30" BackgroundColor="White" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"></Label>
          <RelativeLayout WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30" VerticalOptions="Center">
            <Image x:Name="plus" Source="startbottuns_01.png" Aspect="Fill" HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30" IsEnabled="true"/>

            <Label  x:Name="plusTB" Text="+" FontSize="16" HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"></Label>
          </RelativeLayout>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout x:Name="coinAmountSeg" HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="90" Orientation="Horizontal"  HorizontalOptions="Center" IsVisible="true">
            <Label x:Name="coinsAmountTB"  Text="1200"  HeightRequest="35" WidthRequest="40" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="End"/>
            <Image x:Name="coinsPackIM" Source="coins_01.png"  HeightRequest="35" WidthRequest="25"/>

          </StackLayout>
           <StackLayout x:Name="yesNoBtSeg" HeightRequest="32" WidthRequest="150" Orientation="Horizontal"  HorizontalOptions="Center" IsVisible="true">
                <RelativeLayout  HorizontalOptions="Center" >   
                     <Image x:Name="yesBt" x:Uid="yesBt" Source="startbottuns_01.png" Aspect="Fill" HeightRequest="32" WidthRequest="80"></Image>
                     <Label  x:Name="yesTB" Text="OK" FontSize="20" HeightRequest="32" TextColor="Yellow" WidthRequest="80" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"></Label>
                </RelativeLayout >

                <RelativeLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" >   
                     <Image x:Name="noBt" x:Uid="noBt" Source="startbottuns_01.png" Aspect="Fill" HeightRequest="32" WidthRequest="80"></Image>
                     <Label  x:Name="noTB" Text="CANCEL" FontSize="20" HeightRequest="32" TextColor="Yellow" WidthRequest="80" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"></Label>
                </RelativeLayout>

          </StackLayout>
      </StackLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
  </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

and here is how I try to catch the events from plus and minus ok and cancel images:

```
    var minusTap = new TapGestureRecognizer();
    var plusTap = new TapGestureRecognizer();
    var okTap = new TapGestureRecognizer();
    var cancelTap = new TapGestureRecognizer();

    minusTap.Tapped += minusBtn_Click;
    plusTap.Tapped += plusBtn_Click;
    okTap.Tapped += okBtn_Click;
    cancelTap.Tapped += cancelBtn_Click;
    noBt.GestureRecognizers.Add(cancelTap);
    plus.GestureRecognizers.Add(plusTap);
    minus.GestureRecognizers.Add(minusTap);
    yesBt.GestureRecognizers.Add(okTap);
private void okBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tcs.SetResult(1);
}
private void cancelBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tcs.SetResult(0);
}
private void minusBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (int.Parse(qtyTB.Text) > 1)
    {
        coinsAmountTB.Text = "" + (int.Parse(coinsAmountTB.Text) - itemCost);
        qtyTB.Text = (int.Parse(qtyTB.Text) - 1) + "";
    }
}
private void plusBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (int.Parse(qtyTB.Text) < max)
    {
        coinsAmountTB.Text = "" + (int.Parse(coinsAmountTB.Text) + itemCost);
        qtyTB.Text = (int.Parse(qtyTB.Text) + 1) + "";
    }
}
```

the problem is really strange the tap events work fine on the ok cancel and minus buttons but won't fire when taping the plus image for some reason.

I thought something was overlapping and "stealing" the taps on the plus button but I can't find anything like that .
BTW I'm trying this on android not trying on other devices.
anyone have any idea how and why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found the silly problem thought I'd share my solution in case anyone encounter the same issue.
the problem was that the stacklayout that contains the buttons had less width than the elements it contained so the last element the plus in this case was out of the stacklayout bounds and that caused it to not get the tap gesture

```
<StackLayout WidthRequest="70" HeightRequest="30" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center"> 
         <RelativeLayout WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30" VerticalOptions="Center">
```

this line here I just changed the WidthRequest to 100 instead of 70  because it has 3 elements 30 width each .

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, also caused by the parent element having less size than the tap-enabled child.

In my case, I had an absolute layout (`Inner`) inside another absolute layout (`Outer`). I was then adding the tap-enabled child elements programmatically to `Inner` in the code-behind.

```
<AbsoluteLayout x:Name="Outer">
    <AbsoluteLayout x:Name="Inner" />
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Because `Inner` had no `AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds` specified, it seems the interaction cycle ignored the children. This was not obvious to me because the child elements were visible.

This worked:

```
<AbsoluteLayout x:Name="Outer">
    <AbsoluteLayout x:Name="Inner"
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1"
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" />
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

However, I ended up putting my tap target elements in the `Outer` container, which also resolved the issue, as `Outer` is enclosed by a `ContentPage`.